# Flatten annotations with iText7

Tags: java, itext, itext7

Is there any way to flatten annotations in iText7/Java? I think previous versions had a PdfStamper class doing this, but I can't find it in iText7.
PdfDocument seems to have replace PdfStamper to a large degree, but no flattening functionality?

Thanks,
Thomas

Answer (score 0):

Code snippet below is for flattening form fields in iText7 given the path to a source document and a path for the output file:

```
PdfDocument pdfDoc = new PdfDocument(new PdfReader(SRC), new PdfWriter(DEST));
PdfAcroForm form = PdfAcroForm.getAcroForm(pdfDoc, true);
form.flattenFields();
pdfDoc.close();
```

.Net equivalent is `form.FlattenFields();`

Comment: Thanks Sam. Does that flatten annotations as well or just forms?

Comment: I'd honestly have to check, there isn't any other flatten method in the Core at least